# Separable dual space implies weak compactness？

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, geometric-measure-theory

In Evans’s book “Measure theory and fine properties of functions”, the author proved that any bounded sequence of functions in $L^p$ admits a weak convergence subsequence for $1<p<\infty$, and then the author said that
“*The $L^p$ weak compactness theorem fails for $L^1$, since its dual space $L^\infty$ is not separable*”

I don’t know what would happen if it’s dual space is separable. By what I have known from functional analysis, a reflexive Banach space is weak compact. However, it seems that the separable dual space cannot imply the reflexivity.

Comment: Banach spaces cannot be weakly compact unless they are finite dimensional. Are you thinking of the closed unit ball?

Comment: Maybe this comment means that $L^1$ cannot be reflexive: If it would be then its dual would be separable (as $L^1$ is separable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c_0^{*}=\ell^{1}$ is separable. But the closed unit ball of $c_0$ is not weakly compact. [Look at $(1,1,...,1,0,0...)$].